# Android SDK Installation Folder on OS X

Tags: android, installation, osx-lion, android-sdk-2.3

Any best practices/recommendations on the installation folder for the Android SDK?  Following http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html on OS X and Step 2. "...unpack it to a safe location on your machine..." makes no sense at all for me coming from Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/Applications is the most natural place. Maybe /usr/local for the old Unix folks.

Comment: This answer is no longer valid and we cannot use /Application

Comment: Why can't you use /Applications? I'm doing it now.

Comment: Check out the link http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio0814inbetachannel and http://tools.android.com/knownissues

Comment: I see though isnt that a function of Android Studio? I do not use it but I have no problems.

Answer (score 45):

I install it using Android Studio and i found it here:
/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk

Answer (score 15):

Check here too /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/

Comment: Good answer -- if and only if you have installed the SDK with brew!

Answer (score 10):

4/1/16

I also found it in the gradle properties of my project:

1. Expand Project
2. local.properties for gradle SDK
3. Even tells you location of SDK with path, time stamp and location

[image]

Answer (score 8):

If you have access to the Android SDK Manager you can look at the top of the window.

[image: Android SDK Manager Window Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

MacOs Android Studio

Just create a blank project. Go the project explore panel and open the local.properties file. You can find the SDK path as below.

```
sdk.dir=/Users/{USER}/Library/Android/sdk
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It could be any location on your Mac. Preferable where you have Read,Write and Execute Access.
Please note this is just a starter kit. Android SDK Manager would add packages depending on the platforms you need.