# some conflicts were found in the installtion area

Tags: android-studio

Today , I update android studio 1.0-rc-4 ,at after update finish,tip the following content:

some conflicts were found in the installtion area
some of theconflicts below do not have a solution , so the pattch cannot be applied,
please pressed cancle exit.

How to solve ?

Comment: check out the link http://tools.android.com/knownissues to see if you can identify your issue. I faced a similar problem getting the error message "some conflicts were found in the installation area". I clicked cancel, then followed the link above which guided me to take the necessary steps. Good luck

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the SDK outside of the Android Studio folder, and then try updating it again.

Comment: Link to know where SDK is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698611/android-sdk-installation-folder-on-os-x

Answer (score 2):

I am having this issue today, 2017/08/26.

Renaming the files (adding .bad to the end) seems to have solved this issue for me.

I would like to mark this ([some conflicts were found in the installtion area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27307952/some-conflicts-were-found-in-the-installtion-area)) a duplicate of the issue noted below, which seems to have the superior solution, although it has ZERO votes, and I am not yet able to upvote anything.  Or mark dupes...

Hope this helps.

The following text has been "Stolen" from: [Android Studio Update: Some conflicts found in installation area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28587234/android-studio-update-some-conflicts-found-in-installation-area)

This seems to be the best answer:

"""
I know this is an older question but I encountered the same error while updating SDK components in Android Studio 2.3.3. I was able to fix the problem by starting the SDK manager and un-checking the components that showed the error and clicked "Apply". That un-installed just that component. When it was finished, I re-checked the component and clicked "Apply" again. When it was finished, the problematic component was updated to the newest version. This was much quicker than doing a full un-install/re-install as stated in one of the solutions above.
"""

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem and already solved it.
Because of you changed the Android Studio files, so appear this issue.

1、You can undo what you have done to the Android studio files, maybe you replaced the studio.exe/studio64.exe, make sure the old files ware recovered.

2、Or you can uninstall Android Studio but don't uninstall SDK! Install Android Studio again.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem. I guessed the problem was caused by Chrome so I uninstalled it and I could update Android Studio like a charm.
Yes, you understood right. **Uninstall Google Chrome** and the problem will disappear.
I'm considering to reinstall Chrome again.
PS: I'm using Ubuntu 18.